# I want to build games on unity. Installed on a virtual box , is it possible to do so?

Tags: virtualbox, games, 3d, blender, unity3d

I want to build games on unity. I want to install it on a virtual box.

Is it possible to do so? I have started using Linux on virtual box and want to install unity on it and start developing.

Is it possible. not only unity, but also software's which require 3d acceleration such as blender and others.

Comment: Possible to install? Yes. Will they work? Not as expected or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Unity, blender, etc. all have native GNU/Linux releases. Trying using them as they may contain optimizations aimed at GNU/Linux.

I have not used these in VirtualBox before but other software I use run way faster when using `wine`, so if you insist on running the Windows version, try `wine`.

Comment: Thx for sharing